# SOLR - I have state keyword value as OR but when I am searching for it. Solr is considering it as OR operator

Tags: solr

```
http://localhost:8000/solr/testwork/select?q=state:'OR'&wt=json&indent=on
```

Results:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"state:'OR'",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[]
  }}
```

Comment: If you have a stop filter active for your analysis chain, I'm guessing `OR` gets removed from that - that's the default behavior at least.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the value as same as operator, then please append \\ along with words.
EG: \\OR -- solr_query='{"q":"column:\\OR"}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).